# How can i get video length in java

Tags: java, video, xuggler

I used xuggler to get the video length but it is giving wrong length may be it is time for reading data from video file using xuggler.
But i need to get actual video length or duration.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get it with the `getDuration()` and `getFileSize()` method of `IContainer`. You can do it like this:

```
private static final String filename = "c:/myvideo.mp4";
IContainer container = IContainer.make();
int result = container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
long duration = container.getDuration();
long fileSize = container.getFileSize();
```

You can see a complete example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/inspect-a-video-file-with-xuggler/)

Hope this helps

Comment: xuggler jar file size is larger than my whole project :(

Comment: Xuggler is outdated I would say. Is there a more recent solution?